# Calling PDFStamper.set_Outlines causing type error

Tags: c#, powershell, itext

I am attempting to merge a number of PDFs into a single PDF while also adding a bookmark to the resulting PDF that will jump you to the start of each of these PDFs that are now merged into the single document. Merging works great, bookmarks however have been a problem.

I cannot for the life of me get the code formatting to work. Sorry :(

```
$output = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($workingDirectory, 'output.pdf');
$fileStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($output,     
[System.IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate);
$document = New-Object iTextSharp.text.Document;
$pdfCopy = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy($document, $fileStream);
$document.Open();

## Variables needed to create Outline.
#
# $currentPagesCount - keeps track of current number of pages so we can 
# jump to the correct page in out Outline
#
# $outlinesAL - contains hashmaps what will eventually be written to the 
# output.pdf
###
$currentPagesCount = 0;

## This is where the IList<> should be created, i've been using ArrayList 
## because I am wanting to call .add()
$outlinesAL = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
foreach ($item in $sectionsArray) {
  if ($item.split("]")[0] -match "\[n") {
     $tempPath = 
         [io.path]::combine($pdfDirectory, $item.split("]")[-1] +".pdf");
    if(Test-Path($tempPath)){
      Write-Color $tempPath -Color Green
      $reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader($tempPath);
      $numPages = $reader.NumberOfPages;
      $pdfCopy.AddDocument($reader);

## Here is where the dictionary object is added, must be this... the
## iTextSharp library expects an IList<Dictionary<String, Object>>
      $dict = New-Object 
                  'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,Object]';
      $dict.Add("Title", $tempPath.FullName);
      $dict.Add("Action", $GoTo);
      $dict.Add("Page", $pageString);
      $outlinesAL.Add($dict);
      $currentPagesCount += $numPages;
      $reader.Close();
    } else {
      Write-Color $tempPath -Color Red
    }
  }
}

## Finished with merge, we can close this stuff.
## Page numbers are effed, need to see about renumbering the pages in the 
.pdfs
$pdfCopy.Close();
$document.Close();
$fileStream.Close();

$finalOutput = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($workingDirectory, 
'FinalDocument.pdf');
$finalReader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader($output);
$finalStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($finalOutput, 
[System.IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate);
## Add the bookmarks hashtable to the pdf somehow.
$pdfStamper = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper($finalReader, 
$finalStream); 
$outlinesAL.gettype();
$pdfStamper.set_Outlines($outlinesAL);
$pdfStamper.Close();
$finalStream.Close();
$finalReader.Close();
```

> Cannot convert argument "value", with value:
>   "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.String,System.Object]
>   ...", for "set_Outlines" to type
>   "System.Collections.Generic.IList 1[System.Collections.G
>   eneric.Dictionary 2[System.String,System.Object]]": "Cannot convert
>   the "System.Collections.ArrayList" value of type
>   "System.Collections.ArrayList" to type
>   "System.Collections.Generic.IList 1[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary
>   2[System.String,System.Object]]"." At ~merge.ps1:150 char:1
>   + $pdfStamper.set_Outlines($outlinesAL);
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

It looks like a pretty simple issue with types going into the set_Outlines method on PDFStamper, problem is that it's expecting a generic.IList and when I attempt to use that type, I can no longer add items.

Here is the reflection from iTextSharp.dll:

```
// iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper 
using System.Collections.Generic;

/// Sets the bookmarks. The list structure is defined in
/// {@link SimpleBookmark}.
/// @param outlines the bookmarks or <CODE>null</CODE> to remove any
public virtual IList<Dictionary<string, object>> Outlines
{
    set
    {
        stamper.Outlines = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[System.String,System.Object]]'

New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[System.String,System.Object]'
```

Just have to explicitly set types. Derp moment from me. See above.